# Meaning of . . . "I can make it up to her"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

[(From The Wrecker by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, Chapter XI, published 1892)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_11)

Passage 179

> “Well, and talking of Mamie?” says I.
>
> Jim paused with his trousers half on. “She's the gallantest little soul God ever made!” he cried. “Loudon, I'd meant to knock you up last night, and I hope you won't take it unfriendly that I didn't. I went in and looked at you asleep; and I saw you were all broken up, and let you be. The news would keep, anyway; and even you, Loudon, couldn't feel it the same way as I did.”
>
> “What news?” I asked.
>
> “It's this way,” says Jim. “I told her how we stood, and that I backed down from marrying. 'Are you tired of me?' says she: God bless her! Well, I explained the whole thing over again, the chance of smash, your absence unavoidable, the point I made of having you for the best man, and that. 'If you're not tired of me, I think I see one way to manage,' says she. 'Let's get married to-morrow, and Mr. Loudon can be best man before he goes to sea.' That's how she said it, crisp and bright, like one of Dickens's characters. It was no good for me to talk about the smash. 'You'll want me all the more,' she said. Loudon, **I only pray I can make it up to her**; I prayed for it last night beside your bed, while you lay sleeping—for you, and Mamie and myself; and—I don't know if you quite believe in prayer, I'm a bit Ingersollian myself—but a kind of sweetness came over me, and I couldn't help but think it was an answer. Never was a man so lucky! You and me and Mamie; it's a triple cord, Loudon. If either of you were to die! And she likes you so much, and thinks you so accomplished and distingué-looking, and was just as set as I was to have you for best man. 'Mr. Loudon,' she calls you; seems to me so friendly! And she sat up till three in the morning fixing up a costume for the marriage; it did me good to see her, Loudon, and to see that needle going, going, and to say 'All this hurry, Jim, is just to marry you!' I couldn't believe it; it was so like some blame' fairy story. . . .

I've found some explanations of this phrase - https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/make-up but they don't seem to fit the context. What do you take *I can make it up to her* to mean there?

Comment: You need to look up [make up to](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/make-up-to) rather than _make up_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [**make it up to (someone)**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make%20it%20up%20to%20%28someone%29)  idiom  (Merriam Webster)
> to do something helpful or good for (someone one has hurt or treated wrongly)
> *He'd neglected his children and wanted to make it up to them by spending more time with them.*

The speaker has apparently let down his fiance by going back on a promise to marry her. But he intends to say and do nice things to her by way of ***compensation*** for the hurt caused.

This meaning is *close* to the sense of *"making up after a **quarrel**"*, but it's not really the same. If a restaurant waiter brings you the wrong meal, he might feasibly say *"Can I make it up to you with a complementary glass of Champagne?".* You're not friends, and there's been no argument. It's just *someone has been wronged, and is being compensated*.

Answer (score -2):

In your dictionary, this meaning is the one:

6. Phrasal verb If two people make up or make it up after a quarrel or disagreement, they become friends again.

If someone is angry or upset because of something you have done, you could try to make it up to them by doing something to make them happy again, or by being extra kind and loving to them. I couldn't take my son to zoo, and he was sad, but I made it up to him by buying him a toy truck.

Comment: Thank you. However, I think that doesn't work in this context in my opinion. There wasn't any quarrel or disagreement between Jim Pinkerton and Mamie. That's my problem there. Jim Pinkerton has financial problems, though.

Comment: The actual meaning isn't in the Collins list there, but it's in Merriam Webster

Comment: *There wasn't any quarrel or disagreement between Jim Pinkerton and Mamie.*!? He declined to marry her. She thinks he's tired of her. That kind of thing can hurt a girl's feelings.